# Тонкости SEO (как правильно прятать текст)

Tags: seo

Есть текст, который нужен сайту для SEO, но для юзеров он не нужен вовсе. Вопрос: если сделать блоку с текстом `position: absolute; opacity: 0;`, то будут ли поисковики этот текст ранжировать? Видит ли краулер, что текст скрыт?

Comment: Сделайте просто аккордеон или еще что-то такого!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вы сообщаете в вашем вопросе:"*Есть текст, который нужен сайту для SEO, но для юзеров он не нужен вовсе*". Это значит, что вы пытаетесь манипулировать поисковиками и, возможно вводите пользователей в заблуждение. **[Ключевые принципы Рекомендаций Гугл для вебмастеров](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=ru)**, среди прочих, сообщают как первый пункт в списке:

> Создавайте страницы в первую очередь для пользователей, а не для поисковых систем

и также

> Старайтесь не прибегать к уловкам для улучшения рейтинга в поисковых системах.

Ваш веб-сайт со скрытым от пользователям текстом имеет высокий риск получения бана/запрета на показ, в связи с нарушением **[Рекомендаций Гугл о Скрытом тексте](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353)**:

> Использование скрытого текста или ссылок с целью повлиять на рейтинг сайта в результатах поиска Google является нарушением наших рекомендаций для веб-мастеров.

Разумеется, боты/краулеры поисковиков видят срытый текст. Я **категорически не рекомендую** вам срывать текст от пользователей. Это грубое нарушение. В итоге ваш веб-сайт получит бан и вам понадобиться проделать много работы для его восстановления. Кроме того, вы можете потерять доверие поисковиков, как вебмастер.

Answer (score 0):

1 Текст должен соответствовать контенту самой странице или сайта, если нет то вы можете получить понижение позиции этой страницы в крайнем случае даже исключения из поиска.

2 Как сказано в документации Google скрытые тексты имеют приоритет намного ниже для роботов и ранжирования чем если бы они были видимыми и находились внизу страницы.